# How to fill listview in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I`m trying to fill list view on window loaded event but Nothing comes out.

This is my XAML

```
<ListView Height="142" Name="listView1" Width="371">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="ID"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="User Name" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </GroupBox>
```

this my c# code :

```
  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ArrayList _ID = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList _UserList = new ArrayList();

        using (DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var Users = (from u in dc.users select u.username).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < Users.Count(); i++)
            {
                _UserList.Add(Users[i]).ToString();
            }


            using (DataClasses1DataContext dcc = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var ID = (from u in dcc.users select u.id).ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < ID.Count(); i++)
                {
                    _ID.Add(ID[i]).ToString();
                }

            }
        }
```

Please help

Comment: are you trying to just add it by code-behind or binding is a valuable option?

Answer (score 3):

[`GridViewColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.aspx) work via the [`DisplayMemberBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding.aspx) or the [`CellTemlate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx). You specify neither.

Further i do not see you reference the ListView in your code at all, at the very least you would need to add items via `ListView.Items.Add` or by setting the `ListView.ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 2):

First make on object, i see you have 2 different lists. Just use one object, keeping both data.
Next, like H.B. said, you need to specify what each columns shows. The simple way is to use `DisplayMemberPath`, the more complex but also more flexible solution is to use a specialized `CellTemplate`.

if your data object looks like this

```
public class MyObject
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

your ListView holding a list of these items in xaml would look like.

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="User Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well ListView1 ist not bound to any datasource.

also the generated arrays are never assigned to the list view....

Have a look at the ItemSource Property